# Create an API Connection to an Azure Table Store via ARM

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-rm-template

I'm attempting to deploy an API Connection to a Table Store via an ARM template, but the template below is returning an error -

> Input parameters are invalid. See details for more information. Details:errorCode: ParameterNotDefined. Message: Parameter  'accountKey' is not allowed on the connection since it was not defined as a connection parameter when the API was registered.

I cannot find any docs specific to deploying such an API Connection via ARM, only [generic ARM template docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/templates/microsoft.web/connections) which don't give any examples of which `parameterValues` to use, and [Table Store connection docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuretables/) which seem to be aimed towards the REST API and don't specify the `parameterVaules` required for ARM deployments.

Is anyone able to tell me which `parameterValues` to use?

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "connectionName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "azuretablestest",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the connection to the Table Store that the Logic App will use."
            }
        },
        "connectionDisplayName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "AzureTablesTest",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The display name of the connection to the Table Store that the Logic App will use."
            }
        },
        "locationName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "UK South",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The Azure location to use when creating resources (eg. North Europe)."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "comments": "Connection to the Table Store that will hold HMLR Business Gateway Service responses.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "name": "[parameters('connectionName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "location": "[parameters('locationName')]",
            "scale": null,
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "[parameters('connectionDisplayName')]",
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "parameterValues": {
                    "accountName": "mystorageaccount",
                    "accessKey": "**********",
                    "tableName": "myTableName"
                },
                "api": {
                    "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', replace(toLower(parameters('locationName')), ' ', ''), '/managedApis/azuretables')]"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: did you hardcode the storage key into the template? also, can you try this api version: `2018-03-01-preview`

Comment: @4c74356b41 no the key is not hardcoded, and could you tell me how you believe an older version of the API would help?

Comment: ¿wat? 2018>2016, also, how do you deploy, are you using latest tools? also try this to get the relevant data from api: https://www.bruttin.com/2017/06/13/deploy-logic-app-with-arm.html

Comment: @4c74356b41 D'oh, it was 2018-06-01 in my head! But regardless, I'm not sure how it'll help because the issue is that I don't know what `parameterValues` are required (will try when I'm in the office though).

Comment: @4c74356b41 deployment is AZ cli.

Comment: try to use the same key names as in the docs: `Storage Account Name` and `Shared Storage Key`. alternatively try without spaces. arm template is essentially a json representation of an actual rest call. another thing to consider create the same connection using the portal\powershell\whatever and capture network trace and inspect the rest call. should give you the desired parameters

Comment: @4c74356b41 tried that, no joy. The ones I have in my question work for `blobstore` API Connections, I was sort of expecting them to be the same.

Comment: yeah, i figured those are for blobstore and i was surprised these one didnt work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The parameterValues should be as following:

```
"parameterValues": {
          "storageaccount": "storageAccount",
          "sharedkey": "accountKey"
        }
```

And `"tableName"` is not allowed in the `parameterValues`.

I test it with following ARM template, it works correctly for me. If you don't want to using hard code with storage account key, you could use the [ListKeys](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-list-storage-keys-windows-vm/azuredeploy.json#L212) function in the ARM template.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "connectionName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "azuretablestest",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the connection to the Table Store that the Logic App will use."
      }
    },
    "connectionDisplayName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "AzureTablesTest",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The display name of the connection to the Table Store that the Logic App will use."
      }
    },
    "locationName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "eastus",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Azure location to use when creating resources (eg. North Europe)."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "comments": "Connection to the Table Store that will hold HMLR Business Gateway Service responses.",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "name": "[parameters('connectionName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "location": "[parameters('locationName')]",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "displayName": "[parameters('connectionDisplayName')]",
        "customParameterValues": {},
        "parameterValues": {
          "storageaccount": "accountName",
          "sharedkey": "accountKey"
        },
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', replace(toLower(parameters('locationName')), ' ', ''), '/managedApis/azuretables')]"
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, those parameter values did the job. One thing to note is that they are case sensitive, so "storageAccount" and "sharedKey" do not work.

Comment: Oh, and in reality I won't be hardcoding parameter values, I'll be using Octopus - just hardcoding in my example for ease.

Comment: Why these values specifically? How does one find out what to use in other situations? That's a nice fish, how do I catch more on my own?

Answer (score 2):

Please do not mix up two separate scenarios.

If you would like to deploy connector for blob storage you need to use these parameters in "parameterValues" block:

```
            "parameterValues": {
                "accountName": "[parameters('Template_StorageAccountName')]",
                "accessKey": "[parameters('Template_StorageAccountKey')]"
              }
```

If you are deploying connector for tables storage you need to use these parameters:

```
           "parameterValues": {
               "storageaccount": "[parameters('Template_StorageAccountName')]",
               "sharedkey": "[parameters('Template_StorageAccountKey')]"
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

The values on the accepted answer did not work for me, this did though:

```
"parameterValues": {
          "accountName": "[parameters('storageName')]",
          "accessKey": "[parameters('storageKey')]"
        }
```

Comment: Were you, maybe, accessing blobs rather than, as the question asks, tables? Because the parameters *differ between the components of storage accounts*…