# ARM templates for API Connections in Logic Apps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps

Can anyone point me to ARM templates to build API Connections for use in Logic Apps?

Specifically after gmail, o365, and az table storage.

Targeting for use in Azure DevOps pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create API connection for table storage you could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288990/create-an-api-connection-to-an-azure-table-store-via-arm/51299849#51299849).

For gmail and o365 we could create the API connection firstly from Azure Portal then we could get the corrosponding ARM template.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {},
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "name": "tomtestGmail",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "location": "centralus",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "displayName": "xxxx@gmail.com",
        "customParameterValues": {},
        "api": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/{location}/managedApis/gmail"
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

**Note:** I test it with gmail connection API, but there is a big issue that, we need to be **authenticated**

But I can't find a way to avoid that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed with the product group that with oauth connectors human intervention is always required, whether it being running the auth script or clicking into the portal.   In my case, I moved to the SMTP connector since I'm just doing email.  Bigger issue with trying to use other o365 services.