# How do I find the supported parameterValues for a general Azure API connection?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps

I'm having a problem [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288990/create-an-api-connection-to-an-azure-table-store-via-arm/51299849).  I'm attempting to deploy an API connection via an ARM template, and I'm getting 'ParameterNotDefined' errors when I deploy.

However, instead of creating an API connection to an azure table, I'm connecting to an azure queue.

Instead of getting a specific answer, I'd like guidance on how I can use documentation or other methods to answer this myself:  I'm unable to find documentation on the existing APIs that are supported via the "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS" type, as well as the associated 'parameterValues' that each API expects you to supply.

Searching for a solution here is quite difficult because the terms are very overloaded. Here's what I've already tried:

1. I've tried using the [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Web/operations), but it looks like this browses resources, not available APIs.  If I can use it to view APIs, it's not clear how.
2. I've browsed through [samples on the azure quickstart project](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates).  I see examples for azure blobs but not queues.
3. I've read some documentation on this page about [creating API connections for logic apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/logicapps/2016/02/23/deploying-in-the-logic-apps-preview-refresh/).  This appears relevent, and the author mentions making GET requests to "https://management.azure.com/.../" to view API details, but I get authorization header errors when doing this and I'd hope I can get documentation without operating this low on the stack.

I'm going to be creating a lot of API connections with logic apps in the near future and I need a more sophisticated method of discovery then google-searches, stack-overflow, and reuse of code samples.  **How do I view the entire set of API connections, along with the supported 'parameterValues' that are to be used with each one?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ARMClient](https://github.com/projectkudu/ARMClient) to retrieve the needed paremeters.

```
armclient.exe get https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/{region}/managedApis/{Api}?api-version=2016-06-01
```

For more information https://www.bruttin.com/2017/06/13/deploy-logic-app-with-arm.html

Comment: More info here: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/01/azure-resource-manager-client.html

Comment: `az rest --url https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/{region}/managedApis/{Api}?api-version=2016-06-01` also works and you don't have to download yet another tool.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone, checking it now, you can create the Api Connection manually and check the JSON View of it, it contains all the parameters.

Comment: I don't think it does. Some parameters are secret and they are not listed there.